# How to use opengl to create cylinder effect

Tags: opengl

I would like to know how to create 'cylinder effect', like the top site feature in safari 4, here is a picture

http://www.macworld.com/article/139022/2009/02/safari4firstlook.html

Can you tell me what should i learn , how to get started?

Answer (score 1):

I would start by working through the [OpenGL tutorials on NeHe's website](http://nehe.gamedev.net/).  You might also want to invest in the [Red Book](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/red_book/).  Topics you'll be interested in:  Geometry and texture mapping.  I think NeHe even has an [example of texture mapping on a cylinder](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=18).

Depending on what you hope to accomplish, you might be able to use the [Visualization Toolkit](http://www.vtk.org) to draw a texture on a cylinder in 100 lines of code or less.  There's a bit of a learning curve to VTK (and OpenGL for that matter), but the [vtkTextureMapToCylinder](http://www.vtk.org/doc/release/5.4/html/a01698.html) class and the [TCL example of how to use it](http://public.kitware.com/cgi-bin/viewcvs.cgi/*checkout*/Graphics/Testing/Tcl/cylMap.tcl?root=VTK&content-type=text/plain) are good places to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Please download [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel). It has many types of cylindrical effects in it.Use whichever is useful for you.

Comment: This is a good and valid suggestion, but I don't understand why you posted it in spite of the fact that you just posted a very similar question saying that iCarousel didn't work.

Comment: I have tried out the iCarousel in my application but I couldn't get the desired effect. The iCarousel supports this requirement. I am still looking for my type of implementation. @qegal I have added a comment please look into it.